# Migrating driver project from VS2013 to VS2015 community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, wdk

Long time reader first time poster here.

I'm a Linux developer trying to get started on Windows development in my new job. I knew it would not be trivial but the first thing I'm trying to do is complete and integrate a netvmini port driver (started by a co-op student) into one of their C++ apps. I am struggling to get the build environment going...

The project was started in Visual Studio 2013 with a Windows 7 target. When I now open it in Visual Studio 2015 and try to build the solution I get:

**"Unknown or unsupported property value Win7 for TargetVersion**"

for each project. This also happens if I set the configuration to Win8 (both release and debug). If I set it to Win 8.1 I get:

**"An SDK corresponding to WDK version '8.1' was not found. Please install the SDK before building"**

I have installed every WDK and SDK I can lay my hands on from Windows 7 to Windows 10 using both the web and the VS2015 installer. I have even installed Visual Studio 2013 again but I can't even seem to get the WDK to integrate with that.

The end goal here is to be able to build this (and hopefully debug remotely in kernel mode) from my Windows 10/VS2015 workstation for targets from Windows 7-10. Any advice or documentation that details how to integrate new build platforms into VS would be helpful (all the MS documentation just tells me what I can do if I install this or that, but not HOW to do it)

Comment: I also have this issue. I resolved it by creating a new VS2015 project, and copying everything over. It's tedious, but everything works now. Please update, if you find a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the installer doesn't install the windows 10 SDK by default. So all the installing of other SDK's was useless. I Also found out that by installing the Win 10 SDK **through the VS 2015 installer** it integrates and allows me to build for targets back to windows 7 in VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem after running the Project Upgrade tool.

I discovered when making new configurations that "Win7" and "Win8" TargetVersion are now "Windows7" and "Windows8".

The upgrade tool does not make that change for you but I was able to manually edit my upgraded project with those changes and got it to build for all targets.

Comment: Works for VS2019 on Windows 10